# Losing context after Suspend-Workflow

Tags: azure-automation, powershell-workflow

Below workflow in Azure Automation is not working. Running on a Hybrid Runbook Worker I get:

1. Azure Context is correctly set and displayed
2. VM object information is correctly displayed
3. Workflow is suspended
4. Immediately after the suspension the workflow is resumed using the portal
5. Azure context is lost, getting error

   > Run Login-AzureRmAccount to login.

Running the same on an Azure worker shows same as above but results in a failed job with error

> The workflow job cannot be resumed, either because persistence data could not be saved completely, or saved persistence data has been corrupted. You must restart the workflow. (Key not valid for use in specified state.)

```bsh
workflow TestSub {
  $SubscriptionName = Get-AutomationVariable -Name 'VAR-AUTO-SubscriptionName'
  $AzureAutomationCredential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'CRE-AUTO-AutomationUser'
  $AzureAccount = Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $AzureAutomationCredential -SubscriptionName $SubscriptionName
  Get-AzureRmContext

  Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName AMS-CB-FELX-RG01 -Name li-felixc01
  Suspend-Workflow

  Get-AzureRmContext   Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName AMS-CB-FELX-RG01 -Name li-felixc01
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [Azure Automation PowerShell Workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-powershell-workflow#checkpoints) docs:

> Because username credentials are not persisted after you call the Suspend-Workflow activity or after the last checkpoint, you need to set the credentials to null and then retrieve them again from the asset store after Suspend-Workflow or checkpoint is called. Otherwise, you may receive the following error message: The workflow job cannot be resumed, either because persistence data could not be saved completely, or saved persistence data has been corrupted. You must restart the workflow.

Here's an example of how to do this correctly:

```
workflow CreateTestVms
{
   $Cred = Get-AzureAutomationCredential -Name "MyCredential"
   $null = Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $Cred

   $VmsToCreate = Get-AzureAutomationVariable -Name "VmsToCreate"

   foreach ($VmName in $VmsToCreate)
     {
      # Do work first to create the VM (code not shown)

      # Now add the VM
      New-AzureRmVm -VM $Vm -Location "WestUs" -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup01"

      # Checkpoint so that VM creation is not repeated if workflow suspends
      $Cred = $null
      Checkpoint-Workflow
      $Cred = Get-AzureAutomationCredential -Name "MyCredential"
      $null = Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $Cred
     }
 }
```